# Doubt : About dual boot(14.04 with Windows 7)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I tried to install dualboot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. The Ubuntu installation didn't find the windows partition.

I installed windows on the complete hdd (one partition), then I tried with one partition for windows and no other partition, but still Ubuntu doesn't find windows.

Should I install ubuntu first?

Answer (score 0):

You should always install Windows before Ubuntu or any other Linux distrobution. Ubuntu and the grub boot loader can recognize an installation of Windows, but Windows will never recognize an Ubuntu installation. Install Windows on the entire disk first, then when installing Ubuntu you should get an option to install along side Windows, which will take care of all the paritioning for you.

[image]

For more detail, see [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) in the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki.

Comment: sadly ubuntu still not recognize the windows installation :(
also tried manual partitions again like another post on askubuntu with gparted

Comment: Are you sure that Ubuntu is installing alongside Windows and not replacing? If so, then boot to the new Ubuntu installation, open a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and paste the output of these two commands in a new comment or edit your original question: `lsblk` and `sudo update-grub`